# Dependency injection - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on a maven multi module project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I work on a maven multi module project. The modules are: the persistence module called `entities` packaged as `jar`, the services module called `services` packaged as `jar` and the web module called `web` packaged as `war`.
The pom is the following:

```
<groupId>com.af</groupId>
<artifactId>eMuse</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>entities</module>
    <module>services</module>
    <module>web</module>
</modules>
```

Each module has his own application context file where I declare the beans.

entities-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="actionDAO" class="com.af.dao.impl.ActionDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="milestoneDAO" class="com.af.dao.impl.MilestoneDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="milestoneMarksDAO" class="com.af.dao.impl.MilestoneMarksDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="milestoneTypeDAO" class="com.af.dao.impl.MilestoneTypeDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="studentDAO" class="com.af.dao.impl.StudentDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="studentsActionsDAO" class="com.af.dao.impl.StudentsActionsDAOImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="teamDAO" class="com.af.dao.impl.TeamDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="toolDAO" class="com.af.dao.impl.ToolDAOImpl" />
</beans>
```

services-context.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="studentService" class="com.af.service.impl.StudentServiceImpl"/>
       <property name="studentDAO" ref="studentDAO"/>
       <property name="teamDAO" ref="teamDAO"/>
    </bean>
    <import resource="/entities-context.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Also in the services `pom.xml` I added the dependency on the entities module.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.af</groupId>
    <artifactId>eMuse</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>services</artifactId>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.af</groupId>
        <artifactId>entities</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

And the web module configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">


    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.af" />
    <import resource="classpath*:services-context.xml"/>
    <!-- Tiles configuration -->

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
</beans>
```

web/pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.af</groupId>
    <artifactId>eMuse</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.af</groupId>
        <artifactId>services</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.af</groupId>
                <artifactId>entities</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
 <!-- other dependencies-->
 </dependencies>
```

And when i run:

```
 @Controller
 public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(Model model){

        StudentModel stud = StudentModelMapper.mapStudentDTO(studentService.getStudentById(1));
        model.addAttribute("name", stud.getFirstName());
        return "index";
    }


 }
```

I get the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.af.service.StudentService com.af.controller.TestController.studentService; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/af/service/StudentService;
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

EDIT:It is correct the way i access the application-context file of the entities jar in the services module and then the services application-context file in the web module?

Answer (score 0):

You specifically excluded the jar from the web POM :

```
<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.af</groupId>
                <artifactId>entities</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

This is a transitive dependency that you need on runtime.

Youget a NoClassDefFoundError because you where able to compile the code, but at runtime you need it.

Just remove the exclusion, the entities jar will be added at runtime.

Comment: But the web module should only "know"  and "need" the services module. I am creating DTO especially for this purpose. To be able to exclude the entities.

Comment: In your case, This a DAO that is needed, not a DTO. But in both cases, I believe your DAO interfaces have the DTO classes as well in the signature of the methods. You can ensure some kind of loose coupling, but if you want to use a class you have to provide it

Comment: What you COULD do, is to put the dto in another project, and in your service layer/project, you could map your entities classes to dto classes. I am not sure this is worth the effort though.

Comment: What about there imports: ` <import resource="classpath*:entities-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath*:services-context.xml"/>` ? Maibe is an incorrect import.

Comment: I removed the exclusion. And i get this error now: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.iquest.af.dao.StudentDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.`

Comment: With this import (a Spring import, not maven) you tell your app how to build some beans for a specific id. So you tell Spring to use a class, but then you don't provide the class. This is why you have the exception.

Comment: Does com.af.dao.impl.StudentDAOImpl implement com.iquest.af.dao.StudentDAO ? In which jar is StudentDAOImpl ?

Comment: I removed the @Autowired annotation and the exclusion and I don't have any errors. But it is the best approach?

Comment: Yes this is perfectly ok. Your entities need to be visibles in your main project. This is your Model. Wether you should or should not use your model classes as dtos is a much broader topic.